# Writing an npm module which can be used both server & client

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

My question arises from my poor knowledge in the frontend.

I would like to experiment in writing an npm module, which will be functioning in both Node.js & frontend frameworks like React, Vue, etc.

**Notice: I'm not going to use any Node.js internal module.**

What i actually want to understand are the following:

1. In which way my CommonJS modules will be transpilled in ES6 modules, which can be used in the browsers?
2. Is this something that should be handled from the module bundlers on the client side?

I know that i can create a UMD module, but I'm not interested to load the module as a script.

In addition to those questions, i can see that many node modules are written as ES6 modules.

1. How it is possible to require them as CommonJS module in Node.js? For example a module from lodash https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2da024c3b4f9947a48517639de7560457cd4ec6c/flatMap.js#L1